# Google Script Pdf does not download

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I click on the PDF download button it does nothing and does not download
Export to PDF
The field I selected in Google tables appears on the screen as a table, but it does not download as a pdf.
How can I edit the pdf button code?
function exportToPDF() I defined the section on the button, when I click on that button, the table opens and the PDF Download button appears under the opened table. When I click on the button, I want to download the pdf format written in the codes.

```
function exportToPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Kullanıcıdan hücre aralığını alın
  var userResponse = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('LÜTFEN ÇIKTI ARALIĞI GİRİNİZ', 'ÖRNEK ARALIK (B2:I10):', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (userResponse.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var cellRange = userResponse.getResponseText();

    // Belirtilen hücre aralığındaki veriyi alın
    var range = sheet.getRange(cellRange);
    var values = range.getValues();

    // Tarih formatını Türkçe olarak ayarla
    var formattedValues = values.map(row => row.map(cell => {
      if (cell instanceof Date) {
        return Utilities.formatDate(cell, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd.MM.yyyy');
      } else {
        return cell;
      }
    }));

    // HTML belgesi oluşturun
    var html = `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
          @page {
            size: landscape; /* Kağıdı yatay olarak ayarla */
            margin: 1; /* Sayfa kenar boşluklarını kaldır */
          }
          body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center; /* Sayfayı yatayda ortala */
            align-items: center; /* Sayfayı dikeyde ortala */
            height: 100vh; /* Sayfayı tam ekran yüksekliğine ayarla */
            margin: 0; /* Sayfa kenar boşluklarını kaldır */
          }
          table {
            width: 100%; /* Tabloyu sayfaya tam sığdır */
            border-collapse: collapse;
          }
          th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle; /* Dikey olarak ortala */
          }
          th {
            background-color: lightblue;
          }
          #downloadButton {
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
          }
        </style>
        <title>Çıktı</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table class="table table-dark table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>`;

    // Tablo başlıklarını hücre içine yerleştirin
    for (var i = 0; i < formattedValues[0].length; i++) {
      html += `<th>${formattedValues[0][i]}</th>`;
    }

    html += `</tr></thead><tbody>`;

    // Veriyi HTML tablosuna ekleyin
    for (var i = 1; i < formattedValues.length; i++) {
      html += `<tr>`;
      for (var j = 0; j < formattedValues[i].length; j++) {
        html += `<td>${formattedValues[i][j]}</td>`;
      }
      html += `</tr>`;
    }

  html += `
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <a id="downloadButton" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="downloadPDF()">Download PDF</a>
      <script>
        function downloadPDF() {
          var htmlContent = '${html.replace(/'/g, "\\'")}';
          var blob = new Blob([htmlContent], { type: 'text/html' });
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = url;
          a.download = 'Denetim_Program.pdf';
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
  `;

    // HTML çıktısını kullanarak bir iletişim penceresi gösterin
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(1000).setHeight(800);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export to PDF');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your html code has several errors in this html validator: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea